# How to preview mermaid graph in RStudio viewer?

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio, diagrammer, mermaid

**Background:**

It's possible to "use of an external text file with the .mmd file extension can provide the advantage of syntax coloring and previewing in the RStudio Viewer" ([DiagrammeR Docs](http://rich-iannone.github.io/DiagrammeR/graphviz_and_mermaid.html#mermaid-basics))

What should look like this:
[image: Viewer Panel should look like this]

**Problem:**

In my minimal working example the graph is not rendered in the viewer panel but the plain text from the mermaid.mmd-file is printed (see below). How to fix this behavior, so that the chart is rendered?

mermaid.mmd:

```
graph LR
A-->B
```

**Output in viewer panel:**

- The text inside the mermaid.mmd-file is printed in the viewer panel, but not the rendered graph
  [image]

**My Setup**

- RStudio 2022.07.2 (<- newest version)
- R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt)
- DiagrammerR version 1.0.9 (<- newest version)
- knitr version 1.40 (<- newest version)

Answer (score 1):

**Technical Reason for the Problem**

I found the problem. It's the implementation of the handling of extern .mmd-files in the `DigrammeR::mermaid()`-function.

Within the `mermaid()`-function the `htmlwidgets::createWidget(name = "DiagrammeR", x = x, width = NULL, height = NULL, package = "DiagrammeR")`-functions takes the processed input x and renders the graph. This functions expects an input in the format "\ngraph LR\nA-->B\n", where every input start and ends with "\n" and each line in your mermaid-code is also separated by "\n". But the input from an extern .mmd-file (`readLines("mermaid.mmd", encoding = "UTF-8", warn = FALSE)`) looks like this:

"graph LR" "A-->B"  *(separated strings for each line of mermaid-code)*

Transforming the input into the required format can be done by `mermaid.code <- paste0("\n",paste0(mermaid.code, collapse = "\n"),"\n")`

Unfortunately this processing step is not implemented for extern .mmd-files in `DigrammeR::mermaid()`

**Soultion**

- Build a new mermaid()-function, including the required processing step
- Replace the mermaid()-function within the DiagrammeR-packages by the new function

  ```
  # Build new mermaid()-function
  mermaid.new = function (diagram = "", ..., width = NULL, height = NULL) {
    is_connection_or_file <- inherits(diagram[1], "connection") ||
      file.exists(diagram[1])
    if (is_connection_or_file) {
      diagram <- readLines(diagram, encoding = "UTF-8", warn = FALSE)
      diagram <- paste0("\n",paste0(d, collapse = "\n"),"\n")  # NEW LINE
    }
    else {
      if (length(diagram) > 1) {
        nosep <- grep("[;\n]", diagram)
        if (length(nosep) < length(diagram)) {
            diagram[-nosep] <- sapply(diagram[-nosep], function(c) {
              paste0(c, ";")
            })
        }
        diagram = paste0(diagram, collapse = "")
      }
    }
    x <- list(diagram = diagram)
    htmlwidgets::createWidget(name = "DiagrammeR", x = x, width = width, 
    height = height, package = "DiagrammeR")
  }

  #Replace mermaid()-function in DiagrammeR-package
  if(!require("R.utils")) install.packages("R.utils")
  library(R.utils)
  reassignInPackage(name="mermaid", pkgName="DiagrammeR", mermaid.new, keepOld=FALSE)

  # Test new function
  DiagrammeR::mermaid("mer.mmd")
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can preview your codes as simple as running them like this:

```
library(DiagrammeR)

DiagrammeR(
  "   
  **graph LR   
  A-->B**   
  ")
```

You should be able to see
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uQvy.png)